# unable to insert date in changed format SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have following code which I am using for making report in SSRS.

```
create table #tempdata(computer_name varchar(max),[Machine Type] varchar(max),Service_tag varchar(max),
[Operating System] varchar(max),
Computer_Model varchar(max), [Technical YES/NO] varchar(10),Manufacturer varchar(max),[SSD or HDD or null] varchar(max),
HDD_Size int,AD_site varchar(max),AD_Zone varchar(max), firstpowerondate date,FBODY varchar(max),manufacturer_date date,capacity int,
BIOS_version varchar(max),biosreleasedate date, BIOSY int,snapshotdate date)

--select * from SCCM_PCrefreshdata
insert into #tempdata
SELECT DISTINCT
v_R_System.Netbios_Name0 AS Computer_Name,
case
when v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 like '%Virtual%' then 'Virtual Machine'
when v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 like '%VM%' then 'Virtual Machine'
else 'Physical Machine'
End as 'Machine Type',
Tag0 as Service_Tag,
CASE
When Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%6.1%' then 'Windows 7'
When Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%6.3%' then 'Windows 8.1'
When Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%10%' then 'Windows 10'
END as 'Operating System',
v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 AS Computer_Model,
case
when v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 like '%precision%' and v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.manufacturer0 like '%dell%' then 'YES'
else 'NO' END as 'Technical YES/NO',
v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.manufacturer0 AS Manufacturer,
CASE
when v_GS_DISK.PNPDeviceID0 like '%SSD%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%SanDisk%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%hynix%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%LITEON%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%KINGSTON%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%MICRON%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%NVMe%Device%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%Crucial%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%TOSHIBA KSG60ZM%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.Model0 like '%TOSHIBA THNSNK%' then 'SSD'
                when v_GS_DISK.PNPDeviceID0 is null then 'null'
                else 'HDD' END as 'SSD or HDD or null',
HDISK.size0 AS HDD_Size,
[AD_Site],
[AD_Zone],
CHASSIS.FirstPowerOnDate0 as First_Power_On_Date,
CASE
When FirstPowerOnDate0 is null then '1900'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2011%' then '2011'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2012%' then '2012'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2013%' then '2013'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2014%' then '2014'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2015%' then '2015'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2016%' then '2016'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2017%' then '2017'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2018%' then '2018'
When FirstPowerOnDate0 like '%2019%' then '2019'
End as 'FPODY',
CHASSIS.ManufactureDate0 as Manufacturer_Date,
MEMORY.Capacity,
SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 As BIOS_VERSION,
ReleaseDate0 AS BIOS_RELEASE_DATE,
CASE
When ReleaseDate0 is null then '1900'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2008%' then '2008'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2009%' then '2009'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2010%' then '2010'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2011%' then '2011'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2012%' then '2012'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2013%' then '2013'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2014%' then '2014'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2015%' then '2015'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2016%' then '2016'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2017%' then '2017'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2018%' then '2018'
When ReleaseDate0 like '%2019%' then '2019'
End as 'BIOSY',NULL
FROM [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_R_System]
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT ResourceID, Model0, FirstPowerOnDate0, ManufactureDate0, Tag0 FROM [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_GS_DELL_DCIM_Chassis0] WHERE [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_GS_DELL_DCIM_Chassis0].CreationClassName0 = 'DCIM_Chassis'
       ) as CHASSIS ON [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_R_System].ResourceID = CHASSIS.[ResourceID]
LEFT JOIN [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_GS_PC_BIOS] ON [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_GS_PC_BIOS].ResourceID = [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_R_System].ResourceID
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT ResourceID, SUM(Capacity0) as Capacity From [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_GS_PHYSICAL_MEMORY] GROUP BY ResourceID
       ) as MEMORY ON MEMORY.ResourceID = [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_R_System].ResourceID
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT ResourceID, size0 FROM [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_GS_DISK]
        WHERE [v_GS_DISK].Name0 = '\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0'
       ) as HDISK ON HDISK.ResourceID = [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_R_System].ResourceID
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT ResourceID FROM [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK] WHERE [v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK].Caption0 = 'c:'
       ) as LDISK ON [CM_CAS].[dbo].[v_R_System].ResourceID = LDISK.ResourceID
JOIN v_GS_DISK ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_DISK.ResourceID
JOIN totalrpt.AD_Computer ON totalrpt.AD_Computer.AD_name = v_R_System.Netbios_Name0
left JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM ON v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_R_System.ResourceID
WHERE Operating_System_Name_and0 NOT LIKE '%Server%'
and v_gs_disk.model0 not like '%usb%'
and v_gs_disk.model0 not like '%sdhc%' 
--and MEMORY.Capacity<8192 
--and BIOSY <2017
ORDER BY netbios_name0

create table #temp(computer_name varchar(max),[Machine Type] varchar(max),Service_tag varchar(max),
[Operating System] varchar(max),
Computer_Model varchar(max), [Technical YES/NO] varchar(10),Manufacturer varchar(max),[SSD or HDD or null] varchar(max),
HDD_Size int,AD_site varchar(max),AD_Zone varchar(max), firstpowerondate date,FBODY varchar(max),manufacturer_date date,capacity int,
BIOS_version varchar(max),biosreleasedate date, BIOSY int,snapshotdate date)
insert into #temp 
select * from #tempdata 

 declare @date as date
 set @date=replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 111), ' ', '/')
update #temp set snapshotdate=@date


insert into SCCM_PCrefreshdata
select * from #temp 

drop table #temp
drop table #tempdata
```

I am updating date as

```
   declare @date as date
     set @date=replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 111), ' ', '/')
    update #temp set snapshotdate=@date
```

Even after updating its giving snapshot date in following format
2019-03-11, from SSRs report format I am getting is

[image]

So I need to change one format to get data in database it is stored as "-" instead of "/"

[image]

Comment: Friendly advice: you'll get better answers faster when your questions are the simplest version of the problem you're trying to solve, instead of a lot extra information.

Comment: i need date in format yyyy-mm-dd format thats what its stored in database. in SSRs iam getting 2019/03/06 00:00:0000. even after using convert with parmaters its not changing

Answer (score 1):

You have a few misunderstandings about dates in Sql Server and SSRS that are impacting your issue.

Firstly, you have declared snapshotdate as a date: `snapshotdate date`. This means it is stored as a date type column in Sql Server. You state:

> i need date in format yyyy-mm-dd format thats what its stored in database.

No, `yyyy-mm-dd` is not how a date is stored in the database. Dates are actually stored as two integers in Sql Server, one being the date and the other being the time. When you extract that data, Sql Server Management Studio helpfully displays this as a date string represented in `yyyy-mm-dd` format because the two integers would not have any meaning to the person running the query, and year-month-day precedence gets around misinterpretation by the user due to different international date formats.

Secondly, you are putting the current date into your `@date` field using the following conversion:

```
declare @date as date
set @date=replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 111), ' ', '/')
```

Let's ignore the fact that conversion type `111` has no spaces so your `replace` function is redundant because that format is already `yyyy/mm/dd` (with no spaces). Your formula gets the current date from `getdate()`, converts it into a string in format `yyyy/mm/dd` format, does a redundant `replace` function, resulting in exactly the same string as before, representing the date in the strng format `yyyy/mm/dd`. And then - this is the important bit - because `@date` is a date and not a string, Sql Server does an implicit conversion of the string that you have created back into a date (which, as we have discussed, is not stored as a string in the form `yyyy/mm/dd`, but two integers).

You are doing all that string conversion for no reason. Currently your formula above is exactly the same as:

```
SET @date = GetDate()
```

Thirdly, you are confusing date storage with date presentation. All you need to do to get the date into your table is to assign `getdate()` to `snapshotdate` instead of the `NULL` placeholder you have currently in that position in your `INSERT` statement. No need for the update statement to update the `snapshotdate`, just insert it with the rest of the data and you will have the correct current date stored in your table.

Fourthly, presentation is best kept separated from storage, so how the date is presented to you has no bearing on how it is stored. Sql Server Management Studio presents it as `yyyy-mm-dd` and if you update this string in this column, it will be implicitly converted back to a date type when that row is updated in the database.

SSRS will use the system defined short date format to present the date by default - for you this looks like `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`. Now, if you want to display it differently then you simply need to format it differently in the presentation layer (SSRS), not concern yourself with the storage layer (Sql Server).

In the properties of the table cell, there is a `Format` property for this purpose. Assign the table cell to have the `Value` property set to `snapshotdate` and set the `Format` property to `yyyy-MM-dd` and the date will display in the way you are after.

Comment: Here iam not using table cell date is parameter if it would had be3n text box I would have selected desired format in format butbits date time parameters and iam using in report builder default values available values to change format to yyyy-mm-dd its not working

Comment: Okay, that issue is entirely unrelated to your question. I suggest you read my answer carefully and thoroughly to understand other issues you have. With regard to the parameter display format, this is based on your short date format in your Region and Language Settings in your operating system, you could change it there but I don't recommend it because it will effect every other program on your system and still won't fix it for other people who view this report because their display will be based on their Region and Language Settings.

Comment: you are right  now iam using text instead of date time this is do confusing

Comment: @deepti Don't do that, stick with dates, they are going to be better for other data analysis you might want to do, especially if charting or exporting to Excel. Format the dates how you want them in the report using the `Format` property and just put up with the parameter being formated according to your Region and Language Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format in SSRS using text box properties, then select date and the format you want. It should have the choice of mm/dd/yyyy but if not you can type it in.

Comment: this is parameter and not textbox and only one option iam getting is datetime

Comment: neways i tool text and ask user to enter date in yyy-mm-dd format